# Argument 'DateValue' cannot be converted to type 'Date'. SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

In SQL server I use the T-SQL query to convert Julian date:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,( table.date_due - (SIGN(table.date_due)*693596)),'19000101') AS due_date from table
```

In SSRS I tried to to use:

```
=DATEADD("dd",( Fields!date_due.Value - (SIGN(Fields!date_due.Value)*693596)),19000101)
```

but I get this error:

```
Argument 'DateValue' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer:

> =DATEADD("D", (Fields!date_due.Value)-693596, "01/01/1900")

Answer (score 0):

The `DateAdd()` function expects the date to be in a certain format. Try this:

```
=DATEADD("dd",( Fields!date_due.Value - (SIGN(Fields!date_due.Value)*693596)),"01/01/1900")
```

Comment: I get this Error: The Value expression for the field ‘Due_date’ contains an error: Argument 'Interval' is not a valid value.